# Prestashop 1.7 : How to fetch/display order status on invoice

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying get the order status e.g. "shipped" or "delivered" (or even the order status ID) and display this on my prestashop invoice.

The reason for this is I can then do an smarty IF statement to check if an invoice is paid or not. e.g. if status = shipped, display PAID on invoice.

Problem is I can't get the status to echo on the invoice (by editing the pdf/invoice tpl files.

I have tried:

```
{OrderState::getOrderStates($id_lang)}
{$order->current_state}
```

which doesn't return anything.

If I do {OrderState::getOrderStates($id_lang)|@var_dump} I get the dump and can see

```
 { ["id_order_state"]=> NULL
["invoice"]=> string(1) "0" ["send_email"]=> string(1) "1"
["module_name"]=> string(15) "ps_checkpayment" ["color"]=>
string(7) "#4169E1" ["unremovable"]=> string(1) "1"
["hidden"]=> string(1) "0" ["logable"]=> string(1) "0"
["delivery"]=> string(1) "0" ["shipped"]=> string(1) "0"
["paid"]=> string(1) "0" ["pdf_invoice"]=> string(1) "0"
["pdf_delivery"]=> string(1) "0" ["deleted"]=> string(1) "0"
["id_lang"]=> NULL ["name"]=> NULL ["template"]=> NULL }
```

but "id_order_state" is NULL.

Any ideas how I can check the order status or any other method to check if an order is paid?

Comment: But where are you trying to do so?

Comment: It was on the invoice.tpl in the pdf folder. Worked it out though, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out. Its :

```
$order->current_state
```

just needed to be out of the header.tpl file and in the invoice.tpl file

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
{if $order_invoice->isPaid()}
```

Comment: Why should he do that? What does that do? How does it answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Rob My answer is clear. He is looking for a condition to using in the "invoice.tpl" file.